# При разметки страницы возникает еще 1 столбец

Tags: html, css, grid

При разметке страницы я задаю 2 колонки. при просмотре страницы их уже 3.
что может повлиять на создание 3 столбца? малый размер детей?
parent

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns:  1fr  1fr;
grid-auto-rows: minmax(30px, auto);
column-gap: 10px;
row-gap: 10px;
```

child

```
grid-column: 1 / 4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена у ребенка нужно было изменить линию на которою он опирается.

```
 grid-column: 1 / 3;
```

из-за чего формировался 3 столбец.